# Multiple class with same style but different value

Tags: html, class

I have something like

```css
.padding-top {
    10px;
}

.padding-upper {
    1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-top padding-upper"></div>
```

Which will be prioritized? Is it random or is there a chronological order here?

I have tested the code and checked that there is only 1px applied, even if I try to interchange the order of the like so:

```html
<div class="padding-upper padding-top"></div>
```

Only 1px is applied. Can someone enlighten me on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is applied by order. Try this because your classes are not defined properly (missing `padding` properties):

```
.padding-top {
     padding-top: 10px;
}

.padding-upper {
     padding-top: 1px;
}

div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

<div class="padding-top padding-upper"></div>
```

It will be applied by chronological order how you declared classes. Because you have `padding-top` class first declared it will be overwritten. It will be overwritten by class `padding-upper` which is declared after.

If you change the order of declaration, style of `div` element will be changed too. But if you change order in `class` attribute then style will remain same.

But if you have the situation that you want to keep original value you can achieve with [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) for that property:

```
.padding-top {
      padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.padding-upper {
      padding-top: 1px;
 }
```

Now order for `padding-top` property doesn't matter. 10px will be always applied because it is decorated with `!important`.

Comment: oh the order of declaration matters. Thank you so much that makes it clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, The css will overrides based on the specificity level. In the below snippet. `div.padding-upper` is more specific than others. For more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html

```css
.padding-top {
padding:10px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}

.padding-upper {
padding:1px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}

div.padding-upper {
padding:100px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-top padding-upper"></div>
```

But in your case, both selectors are in same level. So, the recent rule will be applied.

```css
.padding-top {
padding:10px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}

.padding-upper {
padding:1px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-top padding-upper"></div>
```

If you want to override that above default behavior you have to use `!important`.

```css
.padding-top {
padding:10px !important;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}

.padding-upper {
padding:1px;
width:20px;
height:20px;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-top padding-upper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Order does matter. The last declared value of multiple occurrence will be taken.**

Css works the way it is written. So if you are taking two classes in your html:

```
<div class="padding-upper padding-top"></div>
```

The class which is written at last in the css:

```
.padding-top {
10px;
}

.padding-upper {
1px;
}
```

Will execute first no matter how you interchange them in your html.

**Below is a simple example of the same-**

```css
.demo {
  color: blue;
}

.demo1 {
  color: red
}

.demo2 {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="demo demo2 demo1 ">Hello World!!</div>
```